# Hide default message of ais-state-results widget

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, vue-instant-search

I am using `ais-instant-search` and `ais-state-results` to display my data. I hide the result until `query.length > 0`. It works but if I don't enter any search string, it always shows a message. Below are my code and screenshot:

[image]

```
<ais-state-results>
            <p slot-scope="{ query, hits }" v-if="!hits.length">
                Not found for: <q>{{ query }}</q>
            </p>
            <template v-else slot-scope="{ query }">
                <ais-hits v-if="query.length > 0">
                    <template slot="item"
                            slot-scope="{ item }"
                    >
                        <h1>
                            <ais-highlight
                                    :hit="item"
                                    attribute="name"
                            />
                        </h1>

                        <ul>
                            <li>{{ item.price }}</li>
                        </ul>

                    </template>
                </ais-hits>
            </template>
        </ais-state-results>
```

Comment: Do you managed to fix your issue?

Comment: I haven't had the solution for that yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widget [`<ais-state-results>`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/state-results/vue/) contains [a fallback content](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Fallback-Content) which renders when the default slot is empty (this is the screenshot you gave). Both conditions you've written inside your example are false once the App starts. Since nothing is rendered inside the slot the default one kicks in. You can solve this issue with an empty `div` when none of the conditions are met. Here is an example:

```
<ais-state-results>
  <template slot-scope="{ query, hits }">
    <!-- First condition -->
    <p v-if="!hits.length">Not found for: <q>{{ query }}</q></p>
    <!-- Second condition -->
    <ais-hits v-else-if="query" />
    <!-- Fallback condition -->
    <div v-else />
  </template>
</ais-state-results>
```

You can find a live example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-instantsearch-with-stateresults-fallback-yppc1).